# Unique DB indexes in many-to-many through relationships rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I have a data model in my rails app, where many users can sign up to the site (managed by devise) and "subscribe" to a selection of the (many) widgets. The idea is that they can only see the widgets they have subscribed to, I need some way of uniquely identifying the user-widget combination. Then I can define the ability in cancan. I have the following code:

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :widgets, through: :subscriptions
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :widget
  # some sort of unique DB index
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :widget_id
end
```

and then this ability.rb :

```
can :read, Widget do |widget|
  widget.subscriptions.where(user: user).any?
end
```

How can I define this unique identifier, so that is can be used by `cancan`?

Comment: What is "this unique identifier"? What's not working? What are you expecting?

Comment: @Mike I need some property which I can say to cancan, only users can only see items with this condition, i.e. user and widget combination

Comment: Isn't that what the `ability.rb` code is for? It looks like you're saying a `User` can read a `Widget` if there is a `Subscription` for that `User-Widget` pair.

Comment: @Mike, Yes, that's what I tried to do, but it isn't working...